# I can't get Apache Ignite.NET to start up properly inside my .NET application

Tags: .net, ignite

I keep getting null reference exception when I try to create a new IgniteConfiguration instance. This is how I create the configuration:

```
var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
                {
                    // Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes
                    // from the first cluster.
                    DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
                    {
                        // Initial local port to listen to.
                        LocalPort = 49500,
                        // Changing local port range. This is an optional action.
                        LocalPortRange = 2,
                        IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
                        {
                            // Addresses and port range of the nodes from the first cluster.
                            // 127.0.0.1 can be replaced with actual IP addresses or host names.
                            // The port range is optional.
                            Endpoints = { "127.0.0.1:49500..49520" }
                        }
                    },
                    // Explicitly configure TCP communication SPI changing 
                    // local port number for the nodes from the first cluster.
                    CommunicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi
                    {
                        LocalPort = 49100
                    }
                };
```

The exception details don't have an inner exception and the message simply says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

When I try to start Ignite using web.config configuration it works unless I try to explicitly set the port. For example, this is a working configuration:

```
<igniteConfiguration xmlns="http://ignite.apache.org/schema/dotnet/IgniteConfigurationSection" localhost="127.0.0.1" peerAssemblyLoadingMode="CurrentAppDomain">
<atomicConfiguration atomicSequenceReserveSize="10" />
<AutoGenerateIgniteInstanceName>true</AutoGenerateIgniteInstanceName>
<discoverySpi type="TcpDiscoverySpi" localPort="49500" localPortRange="2">
  <ipFinder type="TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder">
    <endpoints>
      <string>127.0.0.1</string>
      <string>127.0.0.1:49500..49502</string>
    </endpoints>
  </ipFinder>
</discoverySpi>
```

However, I have the need to not use mutlicast broadcast and I need to set an explicit port. This configuration ends up using some default port. So according to documentation I can do this:

```
<igniteConfiguration xmlns="http://ignite.apache.org/schema/dotnet/IgniteConfigurationSection" localhost="127.0.0.1" peerAssemblyLoadingMode="CurrentAppDomain">
<atomicConfiguration atomicSequenceReserveSize="10" />
<AutoGenerateIgniteInstanceName>true</AutoGenerateIgniteInstanceName>
<discoverySpi type="TcpDiscoverySpi" localPort="49500" localPortRange="2">
  <ipFinder type="TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder">
    <endpoints>
      <string>127.0.0.1</string>
      <string>127.0.0.1:49500..49502</string>
    </endpoints>
  </ipFinder>
</discoverySpi>
<communicationSpi type="TcpCommunicationSpi" localPort="49500" localPortRange="2" />
```

Setting the port explicitly to 49500, however using this configuration the application does not start, just hangs at the Ignite.startFromConfiguration() step.

So I can't use web.config to create the instance nor can I programmatically start it because of the null reference exception.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looking a little deeper I see that exception is actually thrown by construction of the TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder class. Which doesn't make sense to me because when I decompile it and look into what the constructor does, it seems like it does nothing. Even the base class constructor is empty. I must be doing something wrong though.

Comment: Update, so I got the programatic configuration working. Apparatly it didn't like this Endpoints = { "127.0.0.1:49500..49520" }, but it works fine with Endpoints = new List<string>{"127.0.0.1:49500..49520"}

Answer (score 0):

`Endpoints` is a list of addresses, so it should be initialized as `new[] {...}`. See the example here: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/v2.1/docs/configuration#section-c-code

As for the second issue, you're trying to set the same port for discovery and communication, which doesn't make sense. This are different protocols and should use different, non intersecting ranges of ports.

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference between communication and discovery in this case? If I have Node A start up on and use "Communication" port 45900, doesn't it mean that Node B that wants to "discover" Node A would try to use port 45900? Or do I have it totally wrong?

Comment: Unless this line <discoverySpi type="TcpDiscoverySpi" localPort="49500" localPortRange="2"> configures a different port only used for discovery. So Node A starts up and opens socket on two ports one for discovery (so other nodes can "discover" it) and one for communication which is determined by <communicationSpi type="TcpCommunicationSpi" localPort="49500" localPortRange="2" />

Comment: These are two different protocols within Ignite that work simultaneously. Discovery is for maintaining consistent topology information across the cluster, communication for any other message (cache operations request/responses for example). Each server node must bind to different ports for these two protocols. So ranges of ports must be different.